# Why is statically resolving virtual method calls so difficult?

Tags: oop, programming-languages, static-analysis, virtual-functions

Suppose we have the following pseudo code. I am talking about OO languages.

```
class A{

    foo(){...}

}

class B extends A{

    foo(){...}

}

class C extends B{

    foo(){...}
}

static void f(A a)
{

    A a=new A();
    a=new B();
    a.foo();

}
```

It's easy for us to recognize that a.foo() is calling function foo overridden in class B. So why it's hard for compilers to get this truth by static analysis? The fundamental question here is why statically determine the type of A is hard for a compiler?

Comment: Your code is invalid to the point when the question becomes unclear. Is `a` supposed to be a pointer or an immediate object? In your case it is declared as an immediate object. In such cases most compilers will resolve the call statically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you posted is extremely simplistic and does not show anything that requires a virtual method call. With your same classes, examine this function;

```
void bar(A* a) {
  a->foo();
}
```

There is no way the compiler can tell at compile-time if `a` is an instance of `B`, or `C`, or a plain `A`. That can only be decided at runtime in the general case.

The compiler can't even know if there will be new classes derived from `A` at some future point that will be linked with this code.

Comment: So you mean, for safety concerns, compilers cannot determine the type of an object at compile-time?

Comment: It's not safety - it's _impossible_. What if I compile the above function today into `bar.dll` or `bar.so`, and tomorrow I create a class `D` derived from `A`, compile some code, and link it with my DLL. How could the compiler have known when it compiled `bar` that `D` would be created in the future? That virtual call cannot be resolved at compile time.

Comment: @Mat: Not all development systems for object-oriented languages allow for simplistic linking of independently-compiled objects.  Some require that everything be built together into a blob which contains everything that will ever be linked with it (I've used an interactive display terminals whose development system worked like that).  In such a system, it would be possible for the compiler to know every type which will ever exist that's derived from a given type, and handle things accordingly.  Of course, one can't eliminate all run-time decision-making without solving the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just imagine:

```
A a = createInstanceFromString("B");
```

Now you're screwed.

On a serious note, your example is way too simplistic. Imagine if a right-hand side of an assignment is a call to a function defined in some other "module" (whatever this means). This means that the compiler has to inspect all execution paths in order to determine the exact type of a return value, but that's prohibitively expensive and sometimes downright impossible.

Comment: I think there's a key point in this answer - even for the simplistic case given in the question, it's a cost/benefit tradeoff. If something is hard to do and delivers questionable benefit, it isn't going to get done.